# Multiple reference in single MongoDB schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema

I am new in MongoDB. I have the following schema with two references(`event` and `regdetail`) to two other tables.

```
var MessageSchema = new Schema({
    event: { type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:"Event", index: true },
    regdetail:{ type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:"Registrant", index: true },
    status: {type:String, require:true},
    content: { type: String, require: true },
    createTime:{type:Date,require:false,default:Date.now},

},{
    //no auto indexing at the beginning
    autoIndex:false,

    strict:false}
);
```

I want to know if this is the best way to declare multiple references in mongoose or is there any shorter way?

Any hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: There is something called virtual populate in Mongoose check that out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can.

As per your requirements, your `message` is highly dependent upon `event` and `regdetail`. So, you can easily fetch `message` data along with `event` and `regdetail`.

Check below one

```
var SurveySchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  ct: {
    type: Number,
    require: true,
    default: new Date().getTime()
  },
  ut: {
    type: Number,
    require: true,
    default: new Date().getTime()
  },
  claimsList : [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'claims'
  }],
  surveyAnalysisType : {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'surveyAnalysisType',
    required: true
  },
  assignedUserList : [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }],
  language: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'language',
    required: true
  }
});
```